# Uninstall software doesn't remove all files

Tags: uninstallation, installshield-2013

I've created a basic installer package using Installshield 2013 Premier and everything works fine with default language (English).

But when a user installs software with other than default language (say Catalan), and then uninstalls it again, not all files from `ProgramFiles` folder are properly removed.

If user installs with default language (English), then after uninstallation, all files from `ProgramFiles` folder are removed successfully.

Kindly suggest me what should I do to achieve same result irrespective of language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Raise a support call with the software supplier.  This sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem with InstallShield 2013. A work-around is to delete the path entries in the registry folder: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs\`

To set `SHARED` to `No`, I deleted the application files from my InstallShield and re-added them allowing the InstallShield dependency wizard to find dependencies. Now the installer uninstalls these files without the need to delete entries from the registry.

Is there a different means to set `SHARED` to `No`? For example, is there a checkbox I can uncheck for each file to set `SHARED` to `No`??

Comment: For some reason Installshield has always set this shared dll counter to yes as default. I use the component view or the direct editor or automation to set it back to no.